# CSS Forcing borders to line up in a row

Tags: css

I am trying to have these three borders line up in a row not like a column like they are. I have tried using display:inline-block; and actually went through the entire list trying to have them line up in a line. If anyone could please help me force this to do this it would be greatly appreciated! I am also using bootstrap.css so there may be css that is interfering or inheriting something Im guessing. I just can not seem to get these to line up in a row,I have tried to put !important; on everything I tried also to override it. Any help would be greatly appreciated I have run out of ideas

[image]

**CSS**

```
#content {
    width: 880px;
    float: left;
    min-height: 520px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 15px 25px 10px 45px;
}

.mobilehomesection {
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:#79afe1;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    display:inline-block !important;
    padding:0px !important;
}

.mobilehomesection div {
    margin-left:0px !important;

}

.mobilehomesection ul {
    padding:3px 5px 2px 5px !important;
    margin-left:0px !important;
    list-style-type: none;

}

.mobilehomelabel {
    color: black !important;
    padding:5px !important;
    background-color:#79afe1;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:.8em;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:0px !important;


}
```

**HTML**

```
<cfif len(#session.checkout.vehicle.nospecialvin#)>
        <div class="mobilehomesection">

    <cfif len(#session.checkout.vehicle.nospecialvin2#)>
        <div class="mobilehomelabel">Mobile Home 1</div>
    <cfelse>
        <div class="mobilehomelabel">Mobile Home</div>
    </cfif>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="forms/82040PDFCreator.cfm">Application for Certificate of Title 82040</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/InsuranceAffidavit.cfm">Florida Insurance Affidavit 83330</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/poa.cfm">Power of Attorney 82053</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/vinverification.cfm">VIN Verification 82042</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/odometerdisclosure.cfm">Odometer Disclosure Statement 82993</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/Billofsalevehicle.cfm">Motor Vehicle Bill of Sale</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/Billofsalevessel.cfm">Boat & Trailer Bill of Sale</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/duplicatetitleapp.cfm">Duplicate Title Application 82101</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    </cfif>   

    <cfif len(#session.checkout.vehicle.nospecialvin2#)>
        <div class="mobilehomesection">
            <div class="mobilehomelabel">Mobile Home 2</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="forms/82040PDFCreator.cfm">Application for Certificate of Title 82040</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/InsuranceAffidavit.cfm">Florida Insurance Affidavit 83330</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/poa.cfm">Power of Attorney 82053</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/vinverification.cfm">VIN Verification 82042</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/odometerdisclosure.cfm">Odometer Disclosure Statement 82993</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/Billofsalevehicle.cfm">Motor Vehicle Bill of Sale</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/Billofsalevessel.cfm">Boat & Trailer Bill of Sale</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/duplicatetitleapp.cfm">Duplicate Title Application 82101</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    </cfif>

    <cfif len(#session.checkout.vehicle.nospecialvin3#)>
        <div class="mobilehomesection">
            <div class="mobilehomelabel">Mobile Home 3</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="forms/82040PDFCreator.cfm">Application for Certificate of Title 82040</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/InsuranceAffidavit.cfm">Florida Insurance Affidavit 83330</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/poa.cfm">Power of Attorney 82053</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/vinverification.cfm">VIN Verification 82042</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/odometerdisclosure.cfm">Odometer Disclosure Statement 82993</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/Billofsalevehicle.cfm">Motor Vehicle Bill of Sale</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/Billofsalevessel.cfm">Boat & Trailer Bill of Sale</a></li>
                <li><a href="forms/duplicatetitleapp.cfm">Duplicate Title Application 82101</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    </cfif>
```

Comment: have you tried `.mobilehomelabel { float: left }` ?

Comment: If it's online, please give a URL, I could help more effectively by using the Code Inspector

Comment: There looks to be some divs closing that weren't opened. Line 16 for example.

Comment: Your first block doesnt have an opening div, this one i think it needs        <div class="mobilehomesection">

Comment: Open up the dev console via F12 and locate the CSS within the sources tab, paste in your bootstrap CSS and CTRL+S and it'll apply it. You can check to see if it's overriding then.

Comment: I don't see it sorry, not in your html posted here on Stackoverflow. I see it in your jsfiddle. But that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: And maybe put the bootstrap stylesheet first so your own stylesheet overrides bootstrap.

Comment: @ZaneZ: Sorry, I meant to write `.mobilehomesection { float: left }`

Comment: Yea you're right, an important in first should override non-important in second, to my understanding. Just good practice to put the custom stylesheet second in case you forgot an important somewhere.

Comment: how about to delete the `<br>`s? They should only used inline to format text.

Comment: @ZaneZ yes, margin does the trick ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `.mobilehomesection { float: left }` and delete the `<br>`s in your code.
If you want spaces between your boxes, better use `margin`.

Comment: My guess is that it has everything to do with the line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using bootstrap I'd advice this:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class"mobilehomesection">
  ...
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class"mobilehomesection">
  ...
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class"mobilehomesection">
  ...
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The col-lg-4 already adds the `float:left`, so no need to add that.

Comment: all examples are here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic . also have a look at the Panels, because it might save you some time http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-alternatives (but sure, you could do it yourself)